# aop interception JpaRepository.findAll() is invalid

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-aop

MyRepository extends JpaRepository

my Aop Pointcut all MyRepository Method

all method is ok, except JpaRepository.findAll() method is invalid

Comment: Could you post some example code to make your case little clearer?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn how to ask questions in a smart way, which would also dramatically increase the probability of getting helpful answers. Ideally, provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (please read!). Questions like this one only get ignored or gather lots of "close" votes. Good luck.